# how to assign strings in data frame in R using another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

i have a data frame named final in R.

```
final
    name num status
1  romal   1   <NA>
2 romal2   2   <NA>
3 romal3   3      1
4 romal4   4   <NA>
5 romal5   1   <NA>
```

here are my commands,

```
y <- as.integer(2)
final[2,"status"] <- final [y,"name"]

final

    name num status
1  romal   1   <NA>
2 romal2   2      2
3 romal3   3      1
4 romal4   4   <NA>
5 romal5   1   <NA>
```

i want my final[2,"status"] to be "romal2"

what should i do ?
i will have to access line as y integer only.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to character.

`final[2,"status"]<-as.character(final[y,"name"])`

Answer (score 1):

It seems both `name` and `status` columns are of `factor` type in `final` data.frame. Copying one factor over another one may result in `warning` and value will coerce to `NA`.

**Approach:** Change both columns of type `character` and then try operation.

```
library(dplyr)
final <- mutate_if(final,is.factor,as.character)

y <- as.integer(2)
final[2,"status"] <- final [y,"name"]

final
#     name num status
# 1  romal   1   <NA>
# 2 romal2   2 romal2
# 3 romal3   3      1
# 4 romal4   4   <NA>
# 5 romal5   1   <NA>
```

**Data:**

```
final <- read.table(text = 
"   name num status
1  romal   1   <NA>
2 romal2   2   <NA>
3 romal3   3      1
4 romal4   4   <NA>
5 romal5   1   <NA>",
header = TRUE)
```